# Change cursor depending on section of canvas

Tags: html5-canvas, mouse-cursor

I have a canvas and I want to change the users cursor (like style cursor pointer crosshair move etc).

Is it possible to change the users cursor while its over a certain area of my canvas without introducing "hit boxes" with style of cursor on these hit boxes?

Comment: The canvas element only receives mouse events relative to its whole. To change cursors on sub-sections of the canvas you will indeed have to do hit-testing using mouse position relative to the canvas.

Comment: Thanks @markE so to do hit testing the only way is overlaying other DOM elements on top of the canvas?

Comment: Yes, hit-testing is the only way to check if the mouse is hovering over a shape drawn on the canvas. But there's no need to add DOM elements acting as hover targets. I've posted an answer explaining how to use the `context.isPointInPath` method to hover-test individual shapes.

Comment: Thanks agian so much for this comment if it wasnt for that i would have overloaded and reduced perf by introducing multiple new dom elements!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Shapes drawn on the canvas do not individually receive mouse events, so individual shapes cannot receive hover events.

A shape drawn on the canvas can be represented as a set of path commands

```
A Shape == A set of path commands.

// Example: A set of path commands drawing a triangle
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(50,50);
context.lineTo(75,100);
context.lineTo(25,100);
context.closePath();
```

To change cursors when hovering over individual shapes you must do mouse hit-testing versus each shape (versus each path).

You can hit-test a shape (a path) using the `isPointInPath` method.

To use `isPointInPath` you must re-issue the path command for a shape (but no need to stroke or fill) and then call `isPointInPath` with the current mouse coordinates:

```
// first re-issue the path commands for the shape being tested
// and then test if the mouse is inside the shape using isPointInPath
if( context.isPointInPath(mouseX,mouseY) ){
    alert('The mouse is inside this shape');
}
```

**Here's example code and a Demo:**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;
function reOffset(){
  var BB=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  offsetX=BB.left;
  offsetY=BB.top;        
}
var offsetX,offsetY;
reOffset();
window.onscroll=function(e){ reOffset(); }
window.onresize=function(e){ reOffset(); }

var isDown=false;
var startX,startY;

var cursors=['default','w-resize','n-resize'];
var currentCursor=0;

var shapes=[];
shapes.push({
  points:[{x:20,y:50},{x:100,y:10},{x:180,y:50},{x:100,y:90}],
  cursor:1,
});
shapes.push({
  points:[{x:200,y:50},{x:250,y:150},{x:200,y:250},{x:150,y:150}],
  cursor:2,
});

for(var i=0;i<shapes.length;i++){
  var s=shapes[i];
  definePath(s.points);
  ctx.stroke();
}


$("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});


function definePath(p){
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(p[0].x,p[0].y);
  for(var i=1;i<p.length;i++){
    ctx.lineTo(p[i].x,p[i].y);
  }
  ctx.closePath();
}

function handleMouseMove(e){
  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

  // Put your mousemove stuff here
  var newCursor;
  for(var i=0;i<shapes.length;i++){
    var s=shapes[i];
    definePath(s.points);
    if(ctx.isPointInPath(mouseX,mouseY)){
      newCursor=s.cursor;
      break;
    }
  }
  if(!newCursor){
    if(currentCursor>0){
      currentCursor=0;
      canvas.style.cursor=cursors[currentCursor];              
    }
  }else if(!newCursor==currentCursor){
    currentCursor=newCursor;
    canvas.style.cursor=cursors[currentCursor];              
  }
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Move the mouse over the shapes and the cursor will change.</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you for your awesome reply! What I'm doing is creating a firefox addon which takes a screenshot of all monitors then draws them to canvases per monitor, now im building an editor: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tzS3YgXhtLU

Comment: Oh this is brilliant!! That test in point thing with mousemove makes cursor changing so absolutely accurate! And no DOM elements overlaid!! This is a superb answer thank you so much for this!!! It helps me a ton!

Comment: This whole thing just came in handy to me again! I added a feature to draw lines which are just a stroke. So there is equivalent of `isPointInPath` but it is `isPointInStroke`, absolutely awesome, thanks again @markE!

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if your canvas can change size depending on the browser. When the canvas gets too small the pointer isn't changing anymore. Any ideas?

Comment: Great answer. Can be improved by assigning the path to the shape object so that you don't have to paint it on every mousemove, that is, use new Path2D() in s.path, and ctx.isPointInPath(s.path, mouseX, mouseY)

Answer (score 1):

If anybody came across this issue and is looking for determining if cursor is over the section of the canvas which is the polygon can use this algorithm:

```
 const pnpoly = (nvert, vertx, verty, testx, testy) => {
  var i,
    j,
    c = false;
  for (i = 0, j = nvert - 1; i < nvert; j = i++) {
    if (
      verty[i] > testy != verty[j] > testy &&
      testx <
        ((vertx[j] - vertx[i]) * (testy - verty[i])) / (verty[j] - verty[i]) +
          vertx[i]
    ) {
      c = !c;
    }
  }
  return c;
};
```

- nvert - Number of vertices in the polygon. repeat the first vertex at the end.
- vertx, verty - Arrays containing the x- and y-coordinates of the polygon's vertices.
- testx, testy - X- and y-coordinate of the test point.

Answer (score -3):

You can also implement this in JQUERY like:

```
$( ".chrt" ).mouseover(function() {
  alert('you are over and put your code in this');
});
```

where your html code is:

```
<div class="col-lg-4 chrt">
     <div class="panel panel-default">
       <canvas id="myChart2" width="200" height="100"></canvas>
     </div>
</div>
```